# Как сравнить числа в массиве?

Tags: массивы, pascal

Мне нужно сравнить числа в массиве (массив заполнен из файла) к примеру сравнить 3 числа и вывести наибольшее и меньше первого но больше третьего. Как

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Здесь](URL) я уже писал в комментах как найти наименьшее и наибольшее.

Все, что надо - сравнивать не только с текущим элементом (a[i]), но и с первым и третьим. Тогда получите то, что требуется с учетом условия.

Т.е. код примерно такой:

```
indexMin := 0;  //индекс минимального элемента, 0 - если такого нет
indexMax := 0;  //индекс максимального элемента, 0 - если такого нет
checkMaxIndex := 1;  //индекс проверочного максимального элемента
checkMinIndex := 3;  //индекс проверочного минимального элемента
firstCheckValue := a[checkMaxIndex];  //чтобы не рассчитывать каждый раз значение в цикле
secondCheckValue := a[checkMinIndex];  //чтобы не рассчитывать каждый раз значение в цикле
for i := 1 to n do
begin
    //если не соответствует условиям
    //(т.е. больше максимального проверочного, либо меньше минимального проверочного)
    if (i == checkMaxIndex  || i == checkMinIndex  || a[i] >= firstCheckValue || a[i] <= secondCheckValue) then
        continue;

    if (a[indexMin] > a[i]) then
        indexMin := i;
    if (a[indexMax] < a[i]) then
        indexMax := i;
end;
```

Обратите внимание - изначально считаем, что таких элементов (большего и меньшего при заданных условиях) не существует (index = 0)

P.S.: как в паскале логическое "ИЛИ" - забыл)), поэтому использовал знак "||"

P.P.S.: проверку на соответствие условиям вынес отдельно, чтобы не загромождать условие. Т.е. если текущий элемент не удовлетворяет условию, то его не рассматриваем (continue - пропуск дальнейших операций в цикле).

P.P.P.S.: firstCheckValue и secondCheckValue рассчитываю заранее - просто привычка, чтобы не получать каждый раз одно и тоже значение. Актуально для ресурсоемких операций. Но не стоит так делать, если значения массива могут изменяться во время выполнения операции.

Comment: Немного подправил ответ, чтобы меняя checkMinIndex и checkMaxIndex можно было варьировать начальное условие.

Необходимо обратить внимание на "==" (равенство), ">=" и "<=" - т.к. сказано - чтобы элементы были меньше (или больше) определенного значения, то равные им значения пропускаем. А значит пропускаем без вычислений и элементы с указанными индексами - но это оптимизации, на случай ресурсоемких операций))

Comment: А вообще хорошо бы все делать самому. И исправлять уже возникающие ошибки. Тоже самому.

Если в каком-то месте идет не так, то включать разработчика и исправлять то, что работает не правильно.

Начать с простого - разбили на блоки, которые выполняют нужную вам работу.

В данном случае - первый блок - пробег по элементам массива.
Второй блок - пропуск элементов массива не удовлетворяющих условиям.
Третий блок - поиск наибольшего значения.

Пока не реализованы остальные блоки - замещать их, например, выводом на экран. Посмотрели - блок делает то, что нужно, значит переходите к следующему блоку.